# Is there anyway to fetch all the data from the dynamoDB table without using scan function in C#?

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

Is there anyway to fetch all the data from the dynamoDB table without using scan function in C#? Also Scan function can fetch only upto 1MB of data. Is there any function that could get us all the data from the table in a single go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer. No. Of course you can get all the information from the table, but as [Aws Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#ScanQueryPerformance) states, you can query or scan for the information in a table **at the limit of 1 MB increments**. The fastest/most efficient method you can use is to do a parallel scan in which...

> DynamoDB returns data to the application in 1 MB increments, and an
>   application performs additional Scan operations to retrieve the next 1
>   MB of data.

Comment: Thanks Adam... I will use Scan only.

Comment: @Deen you're welcome. If this has answered your question, don't forget to accept the answer. Best of luck